DIY flexible stone-gravel tile (glued on a soft net) over garden?
I'm wondering if I can find a way to glue small pebbles or gravel on 1 to 2 sq ft pieces of soft net or mesh to create a flexible but durable-enough tile-like surface to cover soil.
It would ideally not be installed, just a bunch of those "tiles" sitting loosely side by side, and staying still just by their own weight, thereby able to be just moved aside in case we need access to the soil under it. So just a decorative small-rock cover that won't fly away with the air from a strong blower.
I can think of random glues and nets to use, but I wonder if anyone knows any that would actually work? :)
Thanks ahead!

Use landscaping cloth, spread silicone sealant over the cloth with open areas to allow for drainage and while wet, spread washed pea gravel over the surface, press into the silicone  and allow to dry.

@DelphicOracle the OP may want to have drainage through the panels; not sure how much silicone would drain.  I suppose the drainage could be at the edges of the panels.

@OP, how smooth is the soil you need to cover?

@Huesmann It is a clayish soil, with occasional common allium plants, although planning to add some generic HD soil under the stone cover. And yeah, it would be much better if water could trickle down. I'd probably water with a hose, this is a small patch by the sides of the driveway.

@DelphicOracle This sounds like a great idea, though maybe an alternative to silicone to have some pores? Can you think of a flexible-ish glue (though flexibility may be not really important here) that could yield a porous surface if spread around, while strong enough to hold small to medium size rocks?

@SamilCan why do you need to access the soil beneath, and how do you expect these to  go around your alliums (allia?)?

Use landscaping cloth, cut holes in a irregular pattern for drainage and spread silicone sealant over the cloth around the pattern to allow for drainage and while wet, spread washed pea gravel over the surface, press into the silicone and allow to dry.
If you don't like the hole cutting idea, cover the cloth with silicone, add your pea gravel and let dry. Punch small holes through the surface afterwards to allow for drainage.
Alternatively, buy mesh backed ceramic tile and glue the tile to the landscaping cloth with silicone.

Yeah, this is the way to go, going to poke random holes after the whole thing dries, I appreciate the help!
